# Problemas autorizando rutas con Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de programación de una RestAPI sobre una biblioteca, así que necesito que cuando hagan una petición a "/bibliotecario/inicio-sesion" o a "/bibliotecario/nuevo" (rutas locales para inicio de sesión y creación de un nuevo bibliotecario de manera respectiva), estas peticiones puedan pasar sin la necesidad de un header de autorización, caso contrario a cualquier otra ruta donde se necesite estar autenticado.

Resulta que no tengo problema alguno con la ruta para la creación de un bibliotecario nuevo, pero si tengo problemas cuando envío con Postman una petición a inicio de sesión porque me arroja 403 Forbidden, quisiera saber qué me estoy saltando...

El repositorio de mi proyecto se encuentra en https://github.com/AndrezNinno/Biblioteca-back

Donde creo que se encuentra el error es en el siguiente archivo:

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/bibliotecario/inicio-sesion", "/bibliotecario/nuevo")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Estaría muy agradecido y atento en caso que requieran más información que me pueda ayudar, ambas rutas se suponen están excluidas de una verificación de autenticación, pero solamente me toma la ruta de nuevo bibliotecario.

Answer (score 0):

lo unico que te falta es crear quien proporcione las credenciales para autenticar a un usuario, el ejemplo mas basico para partir es agregar los siguiente a tu clase:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser("user1").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1Pass"))
      .authorities("ROLE_USER");
}
```

Este ejemplo fue extraido de [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication) pero es lo unico que te falta, por eso no te permite ingresar, por que no proporcionas credenciales.